# BIGQUERY - Query Exceeded resource limit

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am running the below query to join the two tables and get certain records based on Fuzzy logic (Levenshtein distance)

```
WITH main_table as (
  select *
from 
`project.data.Roof_Address`
), reference_table as (
  select *
from `project.data.DATA_TREE_Address` 
)
select
  DR_NBR,
  ARRAY_AGG(
    STRUCT(n.LotSizeSqFt)
    ORDER BY EDIT_DISTANCE(l.ordered_fullname, n.ordered_fullname) LIMIT 1
  )[OFFSET(0)].*,
  ARRAY_AGG(
    EDIT_DISTANCE(l.ordered_fullname, n.ordered_fullname)  LIMIT 1
  )[OFFSET(0)] distance_score
FROM main_table l
CROSS JOIN reference_table n

GROUP BY 1
having ARRAY_AGG(
    EDIT_DISTANCE(l.ordered_fullname, n.ordered_fullname)  LIMIT 1
  )[OFFSET(0)] < 10
```

This query will return the

> Project_Id(Dr_NBR)

from first table and

> Project_area(LotSizeSqFt)

from second table based on the Levenshtein Score filter at the end.

This query is resulting in the below error

[image]

Any suggestions how to optimize the above query?

The distance I am using is from the below function

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION EDIT_DISTANCE(string1 STRING, string2 STRING)
RETURNS INT64
LANGUAGE js AS """
  var _extend = function(dst) {
    var sources = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
    for (var i=0; i<sources.length; ++i) {
      var src = sources[i];
      for (var p in src) {
        if (src.hasOwnProperty(p)) dst[p] = src[p];
      }
    }
    return dst;
  };

  var Levenshtein = {
    /**
     * Calculate levenshtein distance of the two strings.
     *
     * @param str1 String the first string.
     * @param str2 String the second string.
     * @return Integer the levenshtein distance (0 and above).
     */
    get: function(str1, str2) {
      // base cases
      if (str1 === str2) return 0;
      if (str1.length === 0) return str2.length;
      if (str2.length === 0) return str1.length;

      // two rows
      var prevRow  = new Array(str2.length + 1),
          curCol, nextCol, i, j, tmp;

      // initialise previous row
      for (i=0; i<prevRow.length; ++i) {
        prevRow[i] = i;
      }

      // calculate current row distance from previous row
      for (i=0; i<str1.length; ++i) {
        nextCol = i + 1;

        for (j=0; j<str2.length; ++j) {
          curCol = nextCol;

          // substution
          nextCol = prevRow[j] + ( (str1.charAt(i) === str2.charAt(j)) ? 0 : 1 );
          // insertion
          tmp = curCol + 1;
          if (nextCol > tmp) {
            nextCol = tmp;
          }
          // deletion
          tmp = prevRow[j + 1] + 1;
          if (nextCol > tmp) {
            nextCol = tmp;
          }

          // copy current col value into previous (in preparation for next iteration)
          prevRow[j] = curCol;
        }

        // copy last col value into previous (in preparation for next iteration)
        prevRow[j] = nextCol;
      }

      return nextCol;
    }

  };

  var the_string1;

  try {
    the_string1 = decodeURI(string1).toLowerCase();
  } catch (ex) {
    the_string1 = string1.toLowerCase();
  }

  try {
    the_string2 = decodeURI(string2).toLowerCase();
  } catch (ex) {
    the_string2 = string2.toLowerCase();
  }

  return Levenshtein.get(the_string1, the_string2) 

""";
```

Snapshot for Roof_Address table

[image]

Snapshot for DATA_TREE_Address

[image]

Comment: Why are you using CTEs? They don't seem to help the query in any way. Moreover, the become optimization barriers to the engine.

Comment: @TheImpaler actually I am not much familiar with queries. The problem statement here is to check the address from `project.data.Roof_Address` in `project.data.DATA_TREE_Address` and if there is a match based on the distance, get the required fields. Can you help me to optimize this task? I will edit my question and put snapshots of both my tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main query cost would most likely be the ORDER by in the :

```
ARRAY_AGG(
    STRUCT(n.LotSizeSqFt)
    ORDER BY EDIT_DISTANCE(l.ordered_fullname, n.ordered_fullname) LIMIT 1
  )[OFFSET(0)].*,
```

I see you're only returning a single record for each array_agg.

I'd recommend removing the ARRAY_AGG and do a MAX or MIN on the results from the EDIT_DISTANCE.    A MAX or MIN is much much cheaper than ORDERING ALL records and taking the first or last one.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I understand your point here but can you help me out in achieving this? I am not sure how to incorporate these changes.